# How to use Principal Component Analysis while predicting?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

Suppose my original dataset has 8 features and I apply `PCA` with `n_components = 3` (I am using [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)). Then I train my model using those 3 PCA components (which are now my new features).

Do I need to apply `PCA` while predicting as well ? 
Do I need to do that even if I am predicting only one data point?

What confuses me is that when I do prediction, every data point is a row in a 2D matrix (consists of all data points that I want to predict). So if I apply `PCA` on just one data point, then the corresponding row vector will be converted to a zero vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fitted your model on the first three components of the PCA, you have to transform appropriately any new data. For example, consider this code taken from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-face-recognition-py):

```
pca = PCA(n_components=n_components, svd_solver='randomized',
          whiten=True).fit(X_train)

X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)


clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced'), param_grid)
clf = clf.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_pca)
```

In the code, they first fit PCA on the trainig. Then they transform both training and testing, and then they apply the model (in their case, `SVM`) on the transformed data.

Even if your `X_test` consists of only 1 data point, you could still use `PCA`. Just transform your data into a 2D matrix. For example, if your data point is `[1,2,0,5]` then `X_test=[[1,2,0,5]]`. That is, it is a 2D matrix with 1 row.

Comment: But what if the new sample I am predicting on is a single row vector? Then if i use PCA on that single row then every element in that matrix will become a zero right?

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar See the last paragraph in my updated answer.